# Angular 5 animations issue

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I'm new in angular animations and currently following the Angular guide "Entering and leaving" part.

Currently I have something like that

```
<section
  class="row justify-content-center mb-2 mb-md-4"
  *ngFor="let site of sites"
  [@flyInOut]="site.state"
>

...repeatable content

</section>
```

and in component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SiteService } from '../../Services/site.service';
import { Site } from './site';
import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  animate,
  transition
} from '@angular/animations';

declare const $;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
  providers: [SiteService ],
  animations: [
    trigger('flyInOut', [
      state('in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
        animate(100)
      ]),
      transition('* => void', [
        animate(100, style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  sites: Site[] = [];

  constructor(
    siteService: SiteService,
    public name: string,
    public state: string = 'in'
  ) {
    this.sites = siteService.getSites();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    $(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
  }

}
```

Animations module is imported in main module.

When site is loading it throws an error [image]

Comment: Do you have a parameter of type `String` in your `HomeComponent`'s constructor?

Comment: The code is shown. It is a homecomponent's code. There are two parameters which are strings - state and name.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see the scroll bar. I'll write an answer right away.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a `string` in your constructor, and as you know, parameters in the constructor of Angular components are injected or provided, which is called Dependency Injection. Currently, it seems you have no provider for the string in your constructor.
You have 2 ways of doing so:

1. You need to provide a value for the string by using `@Inject()` decorator for the constructor parameter, like so:

   ```
   constructor(siteService: SiteService, @Inject(HOME_COMPONENT_NAME) name, ...)
   ```

   Where `HOME_COMPONENT_NAME` is an `InjectionToken`.
2. Provide a value for the string by using `provide(string, {useValue: ...})` in your `@Component()` decorator, like so:

   ```
   @Component({
       providers: [SiteService, provide(string, {useValue: 'your_string_here'})]
   })
   export class HomeComponent {
   ```

   Where `'your_string_here'` is the value of your string.

I suggest you read more about [Dependency Injection in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection), and refer to this [issue](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/974).

Comment: I wish I knew what you mean. I follow guide exactly how it’s written.

Comment: Was your problem solved or are you still having issues?